# Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 interrupted - now I click on upgrade and the window closes

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade to 14.04 and I'm using 13.10. I tried to upgrade it before but unfortunately the internet stopped working during downloading the files and I turned of the computer.

when I click on upgrade and enter the password nothing happen and the upgrade window hide
so what I can I do ??

Comment: From a terminal do `sudo do-release-upgrade` - if there is an error post it here

Comment: no errors but it this message ( no new release found)

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and then post the output of `lsb_release -r` and `uname -a`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a
`sudo do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only` to update it from terminal.

Comment: also this message appear ( no new release found)

Comment: Did you do an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` before ? Is it a raw version or a variant like Xubuntu ?

Comment: no.
I tried to upgrade it before but unfortunately the internet stopped working during downloading the files and i turned of the computer.

Comment: after that at any time I press upgrade nothing happen and the window disappear after entering the password

Comment: Okay, then try to do a `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then a `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After that, do a  reboot and try a `sudo do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only`

Comment: also (no new release)

Comment: Did some of the previously mentioned commands returned an error ?

Comment: I think, buy stopping the update, you corrupted the packet manager in some way, I can't tell you what's really going on, I think it's better for someone who knows more about that kind of particular issues. Try to reboot in recovery mode and check if there's something to repair the packet manager.

Answer (score 0):

- Open a terminal window and enter `software-properties-gtk`
- Select the *Updates* tab
- At *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version*, select **For any new version**
- Close *Software & Updates*
- Run `update-manager`